# How do i visualise this Data structure written in C++?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Below are the two classes `Node` `List` that i came across in the code.

I am unable to visualise this data structure that these two classes collectively are trying to represent.

```
        class  Node
        {
            private:

                friend class List;

                Node* next ;
                Node* prev ;
                List* listpointer;
                void add ( Node* , List * ) ;




        } ;

        void Node :: add ( Node* predecessor, List *parent )
        {


    } // Node :: add()

    Node* Node :: rem ( void )
    {


     }

}
```

---

```
class List
{
    private:
        friend class Node;

        Node* head ;
        Node* dummy ;
        Node* tail ;
        int count;

    public:

        List ( void ): dummy( NULL), count( 0 )
        {
        }

        ~List ( void ) ;

        void addhead ( Node* node )
        {

        }

        void addtail ( Node* node )
        {

        }

        Node* gethead ( void ) const
        {

        }

        Node* gettail ( void ) const
        {

        }

        Node* remhead ( void )
        {

        }

        Node* remtail ( void )
        {

        }

        Node* getnode ( int i ) const ;
        int getnodecount ( void ) const ;

        void swap ( Node *node1, Node *node2 ) ;

        Node* removehead ( void )
        {

        }

        Node* removetail ( void )
        {

        }

        CsTboolean is_member ( Node * node ) const
        {

        }

} ;
```

My question:

Can you please help me visualise this data structure? Is this graph/dlist/somethingelse?

Comment: Data structures in general form an arbitrary (mathematical) graph, so are not easy to visualize!

Comment: Looks like a linked list.

Comment: Do you understand the basic concept of a linked list?

Comment: basile, i agree it is not easy to visualise graphs, but am at a stage to un derstand, if this is graph or what datastructure is it? Because dummy/tail/head are of type node, but node members are pointing to list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure looks like a double linked list.

A linked list can be visualized like a chain of nodes, each node pointing to the next one in the list. In this case it's a double linked list because each node also points toward the previous node as well.

The CsGNode class is simply what an individual node can do. In this case, it knows the previous one, the next one and also links to another list. I'm not sure what for since the `void add ( CsGNode* , CsGList * ) ;` definition is missing.

The CsGList class is simply holding pointers to the first and last node (head and tail) so as to not lose the data. It's also used to adds the nodes and move them around if needed. The CsGList is the one responsible for the big picture there, while each individual node is only responsible for itself.

You could visualize it as each block being a node, and the list being the tail and head, and using those two pointers to navigate through the list.

[image: badly drawn doubly linked list]

Comment: initially i thought the same what u drawn here, but you have cglist as a member of cgnode.

Comment: @sham I don't see any place where it binds anything other than 0 for that `listp`. (What does `void add ( CsGNode* , CsGList * ) ;` does?) Could it be a pointer to the parent list? When looking at the `is_member()` method, we see that it checks if the `node->listp == this`. This way, it avoids looping through the whole list to check if it exists. 

As for the dummy, it seems to be used only during construction of the list as a dummy node while it's empty.

Comment: sorry kaivo, i have added add() method definition now in the query

Comment: @Sham: Yes, this is definitely a double-linked list. Each node has a pointer to the list that contains it. This is not so uncommon. That way you can remove a node just by calling `node->remove()`; The node can then unlink itself or, usually, call `listp->remove(this)`. It depends on how the code is written. You don't show the `rem()` method.

Comment: i added the rem() method

Comment: rem() is ... if (listpointer)
    {
        next -> previous = previous ;
        previous -> next = next ;
        next = previous = this ;

        listpointer->count--;
        listpointer = NULL;
    }

    return ( this ) ;
}

Comment: ok i didnot understand the answer but me accept this answer and understand it later.

Comment: This is not doubly linked list . This is linked list of linkedlist